# How to fix exit status 127?

Tags: systemd, node.js

I attempted to follow [this guide](https://certsimple.com/blog/deploy-node-on-linux#node-linux-service-systemd) to run a Node application as a service. However, it is failing to start, with exit code 127. Is there any way to fix this?

This is the journal.

```
sudo  journalctl --follow -u serviceName
-- Logs begin at Tue 2017-08-08 16:27:10 GMT. --
Aug 08 17:06:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started serviceName.
Aug 08 17:06:57 raspberrypi app.js[7234]: [46B blob data]
Aug 08 17:06:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: serviceName.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Aug 08 17:06:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit serviceName.service entered failed state.
Aug 08 17:06:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: serviceName.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 08 17:06:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping serviceName...
Aug 08 17:06:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting serviceName...
Aug 08 17:06:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: serviceName.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Aug 08 17:06:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start serviceName.
Aug 08 17:06:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit serviceName.service entered failed state.
```

This is the serviceName.service.

```
[Unit]
Description=ServiceName
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/projects/ServiceName/app.js
Restart=always
User=root
Group=root
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/projects/ServiceName

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is at the top of my app.js.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Comment: What happens when you run `/home/pi/projects/ServiceName/app.js` from the shell?

Comment: It runs perfectly fine. It also runs fine using `forever-service`.

Comment: What is the output of `type node` and `df /home/pi/projects/ServiceName/app.js` ?

Comment: 1. `node is /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v7.8.0/bin/node`
2. `Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        6166268 4446224   1383764  77% /`

Answer (score 6):

```
ExecStart=/home/pi/projects/ServiceName/app.js
```

This is telling `systemd` to run `app.js` directly.  Is this `.js` file directly executable?  If not, the shell will throw an exit code 127 - "Unknown command".

Comment: According to the guide I linked in the question, the shebang at the top of `app.js` should make it executable, because it specifies Node as the interpreter.

Comment: I believe @DopeGhoti was referring to the executable permission - as in, "read-write-executable" permissions set per file.

Comment: "If not, the shell will throw an exit code 127" -- whatever the exact reason for the 127, systemd does not use the shell to start services.

Answer (score 3):

127 is a command not found.

Make sure root user has access to node binary else change following lines with the user for which you have installed node

```
User=root
Group=root
```

Else Try following

```
[Unit]
Description="ServiceName"
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=path_to_node/node /home/pi/projects/ServiceName/app.js
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if node service crashes
RestartSec=10

# Output to syslog
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
#Change this to find app logs in /var/log/syslog
SyslogIdentifier=nodejs-api
# Followig will require if you are using the PORT or Node from Envirnoment
Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=3000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once your server machine is up & you are not able to access server, you troubleshoot by checking logs from /var/log/syslog by the following command

```
sudo grep "nodejs-api" /var/log/syslog
```

**Start on boot:** sudo systemctl enable rocketch

Answer (score 2):

To debug just run this (substuting the <> parts with the value from your systemd unit file:

```bsh
sudo runuser -l <User> -g <Group> -c "cd <WorkingDirectory> && <PATH> <ExecStart>"
```

The issue is the given `User` cannot access the `ExecStart` within the `PATH` you have set.

If anybody is still stuck I've written a step by step guide to: [debugging systemd](https://containersolutions.github.io/runbooks/posts/linux/debug-systemd-service-units/)

Answer (score 1):

For them who are using NVM. try this

```
ExecStart=/home/<you_username>/.nvm/versions/node/<node_version>/bin/node /home/<you_username>/.nvm/versions/node/<node_version>/bin/verdaccio --config /home/<you_username>/.config/verdaccio/config.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey for anyone interested, I had this issue and tried everything under the sun, but in the end upgrading from Node 6 to Node 12 fixed the issue.